# The space of circular triangles?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

A *circular triangle* is a closed simple curve in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ that can be expressed as the union of three circular arcs.  Data naturally associated with such a figure includes:

- the edge lengths $\ell_i$,
- the edge curvatures $\kappa_i$, and
- the interior angles $\theta_i$

(for $i \in {1,2,3}$).  In English, surprisingly little seems to have been written about these creatures.  [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularTriangle.html) provides some pointers, with perhaps the most useful reference being [Area of Common Overlap of Three Circles](http://www.dsto.defence.gov.au/publications/4815/DSTO-TN-0722.pdf).  However, this investigation is a bit brute force/trigonometric/algorithmic, which makes it hard to get a clean picture of what's really going on in the "space of circular triangles."  A few natural questions:

**Question 1:** *What's a (nice) way to characterize data $\theta_i$, $\ell_i$, $\kappa_i$ that describes a valid circular triangle?*

For instance, when the curvatures $\kappa_i$ are all zero (i.e., just a standard Euclidean triangle), the necessary and sufficient conditions are of course that the angles sum to $\pi$ and the lengths satisfy the triangle inequality.  What about the general case?  One can of course express, say, $\theta$ in terms of $\ell$ and $\kappa$, but the expressions get rather nasty.  A related question is:

**Question 2:** *Can all circular triangles be expressed as the image of geodesic triangles from some "nice" space under some "nice" map?*

For instance, one can study the subset of circular triangles coming from spherical geometry (via stereographic projection) or hyperbolic geometry (via the Poincaré model).  What about the rest?

If a global description is too nasty, I'd be willing to settle for a more local characterization:

**Question 3:** *Suppose $\theta_i,\ell_i,\kappa_i$ describe a valid circular triangle.  Generically, how can one vary this data so that the triangle remains valid? (Morally: what does the "tangent space" look like? What's its dimension?)*

Finally, and more generally:

**Question 4:** *Is there another name for this object?  What else is known?*

Any pointers are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: All these triangles are Moebius-equivalent to spherical triangles or hyperbolic triangles (in, say, unit disk model) or Euclidean triangles. This answers your question about "the rest" of triangles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the literature on circular triangles is enormous. Most of it is in German.
Here is a little sample:

A. Schonflies,
Ueber Kreisbogendreiecke und Kreisbogenvierecke,
Math. Ann., 44 (1894) 105--124.

F. Klein, Ueber die Nullstellen der hypergeometrischen Reihe,
Math. Ann., 37 (1890) 573--590.

F. Klein, Vorlesungen uber die hypergeometrische Funktion, 1933, reprint:
Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1981.

There is a complete classification and description of the moduli space.
The connection with hypergeometric function is the following.
Let $y^"+Py=0$ be a hypergeometric equation with real coefficients.
Let $y_1,y_2$ be two linearly independent solutions.
Then $f=y_1/y_2$ maps the upper half-plane conformally onto a spherical triangle
(region bounded by 3 arcs of circles). And every spherical triangle (region, surface)
is obtained in this way.

Of course, your definition of the spherical triangle is different: your triangle
is just a curve. But classification of triangles-curves is simpler that classification
of triangles-regions, and it can be found in those papers I mentioned.

Notice also that fractional-linear transformations of the Riemann sphere act on
the set of circular triangles. By a fractional-linear transformation, every triangle
can be sent to a triangle with vertices $0,1,\infty$. Then two sides are straight, and 
one, $(0,1)$ is straight or circle. This leads to a simple classification.

Comment: Entschuldigt.  Mine Deutsch ist nicht sehr gut!

Comment: Nichts ueber dein Deutsch zu sagen, aber each triangle which maps onto (0,1,\infty) in the upper half-plane thus becomes an ideal hyperbolic triangle. Actually, a hyperbolic triangle is made like follows: you take three circles in the upper half-plane {(x,y)|y>0} such that all of them are orthogonal to {y=0}. Then their respective segments form the sides of a triangle. This is a hyperbolic triangle. However, each hyperbolic triangle is uniquely determined by its internal angles or side lengths, so you may be looking at a more general object which you name a circular triangle.

Comment: It does not have to be in the upper halfplane. When I say fractional-linear transformation, I mean SL(2,C). In fact there are three types of circular triangles, depending on the sum of angles: those equivalent by SL(2,C) to hyperbolic, flat or spherical (geodesic) triangles.